# Possible ways to run windows batch command from Unix

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, unix

I am trying to run a windows batch command from CentOS 6. I would like to know the best way to achieve this. I explored PsExec and WinExe utilities in unix to connect to windows machine and run the required commands.

I am trying this on a windows VM which is within company network, hence kindly highlight any specific network issues that I may have to check for the setup to run.

Any pointers would help.

Comment: You are trying to run a windows batch file.. Where is the code of this batchfile? what issues are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the examples from the PowerShell for Linux GitHub pages, as the working examples seem to cover this off nicely?

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/demos/SSHRemoting

It will require SSH installed onto your Windows server, but otherwise seems to tick all of your boxes.